# How to create a new speech recognition profile in C#?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm writing a speech recognition application in C#. I already know how to train the speech recognition and set up the microphone without going to the control panel. Now, my problem is i don't know how to create a new a speech recognition profile without going to speech properties in the control panel. I want to create a new user profile and select a profile if there is an existing one.

I found an article here [System.Speech.Recognition Choosing Recognition Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135065/system-speech-recognition-choosing-recognition-profile][1]) on how to look at user profiles and set it as default. But the problem is i have no idea on how to do it, and i don't know how to use `speechlib`class and i'm using the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` class.

Is it it possible to create a new speech recognition profile without going to the control panel?

Comment: SpeechLib is the type library name of the underlying COM interface that powers System.Speech.  Project + Add Reference, select the COM tab and pick "Microsoft Speech Object Library".  The MSDN library documentation for it [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).